# A regular curve on regular surface in $ \mathbb R^3 $ being of constant tangent length

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

I was given this in diff. geometry on which I am stuck:

> Let $ S \subset \mathbb R^3 $ be a regular orientable surface in $ \mathbb R^3 $ such that on it we define the regular curve $ \gamma : I \to S $ a regular curve on the surface S and we define the following positive basis for $ \mathbb R^3 $ as $ \{ T(t) = \gamma ' (t) \space \space ; \space \space N(t) = N(\gamma(t)) \space \space ; \space \space V(t) = N(t) \times T(t)  \} $ and we are to show there exists smooth functions on the curve a,b,c such that:
>
> $ T' = aV+bN $
>
> $ V' = -aT+cN $
>
> $ N' = -bT-cV $

I know the approach is that all three basis elements are smooth and therefore differentiable and the vectors $ T' ; V' ; N' $ are in $\mathbb R^3 $ and therefore are linear combinations of the given basis and therefore I can write for the first one $ T' = aV+bN+dT $ taking inner product with the tangent T and using orthogonality we obtain $ \langle {T', T} \rangle = d \langle {T, T} \rangle $ and because of regularity I know the tangent never vanishes therefore for $ d=0 $ as desired I need to have $ \langle {T', T} \rangle = 0 $ which is equivalent to saying $ ||T|| = const $ which I am not sure if it holds with the given data I was given as I know I forgot nothing and typed it as it was given to me and you see where my block comes from, I certainly appreciate any helper's opinion on this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review how the Frenet frame works. Any time you have a smoothly-varying orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ at each point of the curve, you're going to have $e_i'$ orthogonal to $e_i$ (by the argument you gave) and $\langle e_i',e_j\rangle  = -\langle e_j',e_i\rangle$ (by the same argument).

Comment: Thank you this works for me but my problem is I was only told that the basis is orthogonal not orthonormal hence I do not know the tangent is of unit length, so that was my problem do you think the author's intention was that the basis be orthonormal? Meaning the tangent should have been normalized as no one told me it was of constant length

Comment: Yes, without constant length it won't be true. $T'$ will have a $T$ component if the length varies. $N$ is by definition a unit vector, and $V$ will have constant length if $T$ does. Ordinarily, curves are always taken to be arclength parametrized in the abstract setting.

Comment: @zbigniew2015 as Ted Shifrin mentioned your curve must be parametrized by arc length. Also, the trihedron $\{T,N,V\}$ you have above is called the Darboux trihedron and the functions $a,b,c$ you will obtain are the geodesic curvature, the normal curvature and the geodesic torsion of the curve $\gamma$ respectively. For more see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_frame)